# Can we make those who sign up to our page automatically follow our Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, twitter

Is it possible to make somebody that logs in with Facebook automatically like our Facebook page?

I have the same question about Twitter. If anyone logs in via Twitter, can they automatically follow us?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to force your users to like your Facebook page when they signup? I would never do this. Imagine you sign up for a page and you notice that they automatically added a Facebook like without asking you.

Instead of this place a box with the "Like" button on the page that is shown after signup.

Answer (score 0):

With the way that this works, you have to ask if they want to follow you. You can not force them to do anything vai social networking.

When websites, logins, and applications interact with Twitter, Facebook, and other social networks, you have to be clear of what you are taking from their profiles regarding information such as:

- Profile Picture
- Date of Birth
- Ability to use Login with ServiceName

Also, along with that, you can send them a notification to `Like` the page, but you can not force them. If I remember correctly, that is against the Terms of Service and what OAuth is about.